# Yii2 .htaccess redirect to backend part

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have installed Yii2 advanced app and what i am trying to do now is to redirect this url `htpp://site/admin` to the backend ( admin ) side. What i tried so far is:

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8

Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*
RewriteEngine on


# Make the backend accessible via url: http://site/admin
RewriteRule ^admin$ $admin.php [L]

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php


RewriteRule ^static - [L]
```

I am not familiar whit `.htaccess` and i am not pretty sure what is the right way. This code is what i found after googling. The `.htaccess` file is in the `app/backend/web/.htaccess`. Can you point me the right way? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Im afraid you need to do it in Apache/nginx config because your server needs to point to the backend index.php Otherwise it does'nt know what to serve. Htaccess can add rules after the page has been served. Rules for sub pages etc.

Comment: You should probably use Virtual Host to configure this

Answer (score 0):

easy :

```
RewriteEngine On

# End the processing, if a rewrite already occurred
RewriteRule ^(frontend|backend)/web/ - [L]

# Handle the case of backend, skip ([S=1]) the following rule, if current matched
RewriteRule ^admin(/(.*))?$ backend/web/$2 [S=1]

# handle the case of frontend
RewriteRule .* frontend/web/$0

# Uncomment the following, if you want speaking URL
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteRule ^([^/]+/web)/.*$ $1/index.php
```